# Difference between 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 in access control lists

Tags: ipv6, access-control-list, ipv4

When setting up access control lists, what's the difference between `0.0.0.0/0` and `::/0`?

I'm seeing this for an AWS EC2 instance I'm setting up

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**0.0.0.0/0** is the **IPv4** everything - all possible **IPv4** addresses.
**::/0** is the **IPv6** equivalent of that.

You can, for example, allow IPv4 and disallow IPv6 or vice versa.

@kasperd mentions:

It should be noted that depending on implementation **::/0** can mean either all IPv6 addresses or all **IPv4** and **IPv6** addresses. That's because **IPv4** addresses can be mapped into **IPv6** addresses **::ffff:0:0/96**

More info on **IPv6** is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address).

Comment: It should be noted that depending on implementation `::/0` can mean either all IPv6 addresses or all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. That's because IPv4 addresses can be mapped into IPv6 addresses `::ffff:0:0/96`.

Comment: Any idea in what context EC2 uses it? Would be good to know.

Comment: Isn't that just a firewall ? By default everything should be allowed from anywhere. If you remove those rules before adding your public subnets you might loose connectivity to the instances.

Comment: I believe Amazon implementation follows:
0.0.0.0/0 for IPv4 everything  and ::/0 for IPv6

Answer (score 7):

`0.0.0.0/0` is IPv4 and `::/0` is the default route address for IPv6  covering all addresses.